# Mail is being delivered to /var/mail/*user* instead of Maildir

Tags: postfix

We are migrating an old Debian 6 Postfix smarthost/relay server to a new one, just copying the configuration files and environment files to a new Ubuntu 20.04 system.

For some reason, in the new environment, **mail is being delivered to /var/mail/*user* instead of Maildir (/home/vmail/user/Maildir).**

Here's the *postconf -n* output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
default_destination_recipient_limit = 100
default_process_limit = 50
inet_protocols = ipv4
insiders_bind = yes
insiders_bind_dn = cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=root
insiders_bind_pw = ******
insiders_query_filter = (|(&(mail=%s)(externalmail=local_only))(&(uid=%u)(externalmail=local_only)))
insiders_result_attribute = externalmail
insiders_search_base = dc=root
insiders_server_host = ldap.domain.com
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
local_only = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domains, reject
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 10000000000
message_size_limit = 20971520
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mailbackend1
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.2.0/24
myorigin = domain.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_helo_name = mail.domain.com
smtp_host_lookup = dns, native
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = mailbackend1
smtpd_hard_error_limit = ${stress?5}${stress:20}
smtpd_junk_command_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:100}
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access ldap:insiders, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/frontends, reject_unauth_destination, reject
smtpd_restriction_classes = local_only
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_soft_error_limit = ${stress?2}${stress:10}
smtpd_timeout = ${stress?60}${stress:300}
uiduser_bind = yes
uiduser_bind_dn = cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=root
uiduser_bind_pw = ******
uiduser_query_filter = (uid=%u)
uiduser_result_attribute = uidNumber
uiduser_search_base = dc=root
uiduser_server_host = ldap.domain.com
uiduser_server_port = 389
valiases_bind = yes
valiases_bind_dn = cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=root
valiases_bind_pw = ******
valiases_query_filter = (&(mail=%s)(!(mail=pendiente)))
valiases_result_attribute = uid
valiases_search_base = dc=root
valiases_server_host = ldap.domain.com
valiases_server_port = 389
valiases_version = 3
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:valiases
virtual_gid_maps = static:10000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = domain.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 10000
virtual_transport = local
virtual_uid_maps = ldap:uiduser
vmailbox_bind = yes
vmailbox_bind_dn = cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=root
vmailbox_bind_pw = ******
vmailbox_query_filter = (uid=%u)
vmailbox_result_attribute = uid
vmailbox_result_format = %s/Maildir/
vmailbox_search_base = dc=root
vmailbox_server_host = ldap.domain.com
vmailbox_server_port = 389
```

Comment: did you upgrade one r by one version or do you just setup a fresh one and only copy the config files?

Comment: setup a fresh ubuntu 20.04 and copied the config files

Comment: At first glance: `mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail` ;  that means that postfix hands over messages to procmail for local delivery and to write them to the correct location. Did you also copy the ~/.procmailrc files that are the primary method  to govern procmail behaviour - and you don't have `home_mailbox` setting that will be used as the fallback/default by procmail when no .procmailrc is found

Comment: The old server doesn't have procmailrc for each inbox and is still working, neither home_mailbox param